# How to target all classes with javascript. No jQuery

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I am writing a responsive program that keeps changing the width of sertain elements, corresponding to other elements which have a % based width. Which works fine. But i ran into a problem when i wanted to change all images in side a div to be as big as the grand parent of the images.

JS:

```
var thebigone = document.getElementById('imgpresentation');
var demimages = document.getElementsByClassName('presentatinthis');

fixtheresponsiveness = setInterval(fixthis,1000);
function fixthis()
{
    demimages.style.width = thebigone.offsetWidth+"px";
}

fixtheresponsiveness();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="imgpresentation" class="imgpresentation">
    <div id="slidethemimgpresentation" class="slidethemimgpresentation">
        <img class="presentatinthis" src="img/billeder/xyachtvisit/xyachtbesoeg1.jpg"/>
        <img class="presentatinthis" src="img/billeder/xyachtvisit/xyachtbesoeg2.jpg"/>
        <img class="presentatinthis" src="img/billeder/xyachtvisit/xyachtbesoeg3.jpg"/>
        <img class="presentatinthis" src="img/billeder/xyachtvisit/xyachtbesoeg4.jpg"/>
        <img class="presentatinthis" src="img/billeder/xyachtvisit/xyachtbesoeg5.jpg"/>
        <img class="presentatinthis" src="img/billeder/xyachtvisit/xyachtbesoeg6.jpg"/>
        <img class="presentatinthis" src="img/billeder/xyachtvisit/xyachtbesoeg7.jpg"/>
        <img class="presentatinthis" src="img/billeder/xyachtvisit/xyachtbesoeg8.jpg"/>
        <img class="presentatinthis" src="img/billeder/xyachtvisit/xyachtbesoeg9.jpg"/>
        <img class="presentatinthis" src="img/billeder/xyachtvisit/xyachtbesoeg10.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works if i replace "class" with "id" and "getelementsbyclassname" with "getelementbyid" but then it only works on the first img inside the div.

I do not wish to use jQuery, so please do not suggest $('.presentatinthis')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a [*NodeList*,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which means you would have to loop over the result to access and set each *Node's* `style`

```
var i = demimages.length;
while (i--) demimages[i].style.width = thebigone.offsetWidth+"px";
```

Comment: Yes, you can use your favourite type of loop though, I just use `while` like this sometimes because I find it easy to type.

Comment: Thank you so much! There are just some things i don't understand about the code and i hate that....

What is the arguments in the while loop?

Comment: @KristianDaugaard `while (i--)` means "`while` tests `i` is non-zero, then does `i = i - 1`. If the test was true, do loop code". Think of it like `var i; for (i = demimages.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1)`

Comment: Okay i think i got it. But where does the i variable increment so that the demimages[i] works?

Comment: @KristianDaugaard it decrements, it doesn't increment, and it happens in the test for the `while`

Comment: See MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#--_.28Decrement.29